# How to define namespace for imported project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, namespaces

I'm getting really stuck trying to refer to methods/classes in a project imported into a blank project. The exact steps to recreate this are as follows

1. Download and Extract into a temp folder http://mywsat.codeplex.com/
2. Create a new project in VS - Asp.Net Empty Web Application .NET 3.5 named WebApplication1
3. Copy all files from MYWSAT35 folder across to the new project
4. In VS solution explorer, select Show all files

If you now build and run the project runs fine with no errors.

5  In VS solution explorer, for all of the imported files right click and select Include in Project

Now try rebuilding the project I get the error

```
    The type or namespace name 'GetAdminMasterPage' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

GetAdminMasterPage.cs is located in `WebApplication1\App_Code\class\GetAdminMasterPage.cs` and looks like this

```
#region using references
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Caching;
using System.Web.UI;
#endregion

/// <summary>
/// Gets the MasterPage for the user selected Admin Theme.
/// </summary>
public class GetAdminMasterPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    #region Get Admin MasterPage

    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Cache["cachedAdminMaster"] == null)
        {
            GetDefaultMasterPage();
        }
        else
        {
            string loadMasterFromCache = Cache["cachedAdminMaster"].ToString();
            Page.MasterPageFile = loadMasterFromCache;
        }
    }

    private void GetDefaultMasterPage()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbMyCMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_admin_SelectMasterPage", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult);

            if (myReader.Read())
            {
                string masterPageFileName = myReader["ThemeUrl"] as string;
                Cache.Insert("cachedAdminMaster", masterPageFileName, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(300), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
                Page.MasterPageFile = masterPageFileName;
            }

            myReader.Close();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

An example of one of the methods that now gives an error is

```
using System;

public partial class admin_admin_edit_css : GetAdminMasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

//gives error The type or namespace name 'GetAdminMasterPage' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

So I know I must refer to GetAdminMasterPage with `Using xxxxxx;` but just can't figure out the correct syntax.

Firstly why does the error only occur when I select "Include In Project" and not when just copied?

Secondly, how do I fix the error with the correct path to the GetAdminMasterPage?

Comment: Was the original code a Web Site "project"? Is your blank project a Web Application Project?

Comment: Yes I think so. Does that mean it's not possible?

Comment: It means that you're mixing apples with oranges and should expect trouble. I recommend taking the downloaded site locally, right click and convert to web application, then try to use that code.

Comment: I do need to convert it to an application as I want to combine it with an existing web application. If you add that as an answer I'll accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After opening the project as a web site, right-click the project and choose "Convert to Web Application". The result of the conversion is what you'll want to move to your blank project, or perhaps you'll want to leave the changes in place.

Comment: Thanks - This link was very useful http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project.aspx

Answer (score 2):

**Note: you do not create a new project.**

1.Copy the MYWSAT35 folder in a drive (for example: d:\MYWSAT35)
2.in Visual Studio go to File -> Open web site
3.select d:\MYWSAT35 and click on open
4.press F5 key to run application

Answer (score 2):

You have to open the project as a web site.

If you are using VS2010, then it will prompt you for upgrade to .net 4.0. You can choose no.

But if you are opening in VS2012, it will open it with no prompts.

Both will build successfully.